# CSS property margin-top:-10px animation with Jquery affects the following divs, how can I make them fixed?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, margin, effect

I want to make a hover effect to bounce an icon but to have a fixed shadow below.
So i'm using Jquery with hover and animating the margin-top.
what happends that the image block drags the shadow  when it changes it's margin-top
How can I fix the shadow in it's position?

here's my code

```
<style>
#icons
{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: auto;
}
#icons li
{
float: left;
height: 170px;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#icons li a.img_bounce
{
display: block;
border: 0px;
}

#icons li img.img_shadow
{
display: block;
border: 0px;

}


</style>

<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("#icons a.img_bounce").hover(function(){
jQuery(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.75, marginTop: -10}, 400);
},function(){
jQuery(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0, marginTop: 0}, 400);
});


});
</script>

<ul id="icons">
    <li><a href="" class="img_bounce"><img  alt="Firefox" src="Firefox.png"  width="128" height="128" style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></a><img class="img_shadow" width="128" alt="Chrome" src="shadow.png"  style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></li>
    <li><a href="" class="img_bounce"><img  alt="Firefox" src="Firefox.png"  width="128" height="128" style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></a><img class="img_shadow" width="128" alt="Chrome" src="shadow.png"  style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></li>
    <li><a href="" class="img_bounce"><img  alt="Firefox" src="Firefox.png"  width="128" height="128" style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></a><img class="img_shadow" width="128" alt="Chrome" src="shadow.png"  style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></li>
    <li><a href="" class="img_bounce"><img  alt="Firefox" src="Firefox.png"  width="128" height="128" style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></a><img class="img_shadow" width="128" alt="Chrome" src="shadow.png"  style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;"></li>

</ul>
```

[image]

I've found out that by adding on the animation a height

```
on hover
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.75, marginTop: -10,height:138}, 400);
on hover out
    jQuery(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.75, marginTop: -10,height:128}, 400);
```

it works but.. the original height is somehow modified...it's not the original
so modifies the original position of the shadow...after one hover...

Comment: have you tried setting the margin-bottom or padding-bottom or the top image to equal the amount you have moved the div up?

Answer (score 1):

A really quick solution for this would be to add some padding/margin to the bottom at the same time.
What is happening just now is that because you are moving one element using the margin, then the other elements are just going to move with it as they are relatively positioned to it.

If you add in the extra padding/margin at the bottom (one or the other) then the shadow image should stay in the same position.

Comment: you're right, it works... height wasn't a good ideea, but maring-bottom is ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be helpful to you.

Site:
http://www.adrianpelletier.com/2009/05/31/create-a-realistic-hover-effect-with-jquery-ui/

Demo:
http://adrianpelletier.com/sandbox/jquery_hover_nav/

On a side note: Is that icon "ChromeFox" or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `position: relative` to `#icons li a.img_bounce`, and then animate the `top` property instead of `margin-top`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/uexTM/